# How do I make a deep copy in a constructors initialization list. c++

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, initialization-list

This is the constructor for node in list class. I need to make a deep copy of winery, an other class in the initialization list. Item is an instance of winery.

```
List::Node::Node(const Winery& winery) : 
    item(winery)
    // your initialization list here
{
    Winery w = winery;
    item = w;
}
```

constructor for winery:

```
Winery::Winery(const char * const name, const char * const location,
        const int acres, const int rating) :
    name(name),
    location(location),
    acres(acres),
    rating(rating)
{
    char    *nm = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    char    *loc = new char[strlen(location) + 1];
    strcpy(nm, this->name);
    strcpy(loc, this->location);
    this->name = nm;
    this->location = loc;
    this->acres = acres;
    this->rating = rating;
}
```

Comment: Make a ctor for `winery` which makes a deep-copy. BTW: The ctor-init-list and the ctor-body look like they duplicate each others work.

Comment: You're right, I'll take that out. I added the code that I have for the winery constructor.

Comment: "deep copy" vs "shallow copy" are terms usually only used in GC-only languages that don't have direct support for values (as opposed to only pointers).

Comment: Seems you are repeating that in the `Winery`-ctor. Also, consider investing in some `std::unique_ptr`s for exception-safety and easer cleanup (hope you had a dtor, copy-ctor, and assingment-operator defined as well...). If `Winery` only has those 4 members, you are already doing a deep-copy there.

Comment: @o11c "shallow" vs "deep" copy are commonly used in C++. Values often wrap allocations which you may or may not want to copy depending on situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no reson to copy the winery three times in the Node-ctor.
Once is enough:

```
List::Node::Node(const Winery& winery) : item(winery) {}
```

You might add a move-ctor though (C++11 and later):

```
List::Node::Node(Winery&& winery) : item(std::move(winery)) {}
```

Similar for `Winery`.
If those four are all the members, the `Winery`-ctor already does a deep-copy.

I hope you remembered the rule-of-3 and also provided a custom copy-ctor, copy-assignment-operator and dtor.
Still, better would be using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

Also, the top-level cv-qualifiers are useless, thus I removed them.

```
Winery::Winery(const char * name, const char * location,
        int acres, int rating) :
    name(strcpy(new char[strlen(name)+1], name),
    location(strcpy(new char[strlen(location)+1], location),
    acres(acres),
    rating(rating)
{}
```

Comment: Does the initialization list use deep copy? If I modify winery externally, then item will change?

Comment: @LiTaiji The ctor-init-list initializes the elements with the expression you give them. Whether that means deep-copy or not depends on the members. BTW: Use ctor-init-list to disambiguate from initializer_list and braced-init-list, which are different things.

Comment: That is, for instances of classes that do not provide a copy constructor,  ctor-init-list uses shallow copy.