# Initialize struct with deep copy of object passed by reference

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I am working on an assignment for a class, and have a linked list that holds an object in each node. The nodes are implemented as structs. I am having trouble initializing the object because it seems I need to make a deep copy, but am not. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to make it a deep copy. Every time the original object is deleted, the name and location get deleted as well.

I know that other students in the same class have asked similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310837/how-do-i-make-a-deep-copy-in-a-constructors-initialization-list-c), but my code is the same and I still end up with problems.

The nodes are constructed like so:

```
List::Node::Node(const Winery& winery) :
    item(winery),
    nextByName(nullptr),
    nextByRating(nullptr)
{
}
```

The definition of the Node struct:

```
struct Node
    {
        Node(const Winery& winery);     // constructor
        Winery item;                    // an instance of winery
                                        // (NOT a pointer to an instance)
        Node *nextByName;               // next node in the name thread
        Node *nextByRating;             // next node in the rating thread
    };
```

The winery class is constructed like so:

```
Winery::Winery(const char * const name, const char * const location, const int acres, const int rating) :
    name(new char[strlen(name) + 1]),
    location(new char[strlen(location) + 1]),
    acres(acres),
    rating(rating)
{
    strcpy(this->name, name);
    strcpy(this->location, location);
}
```

I am fairly certain this is making a deep copy, so the problem is in the construction of the node, not the winery.

Comment: You need a copy constructor in `Winery`. The constructor you've shown is not the one used by `item(winery)`. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was what I was missing. Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?